# wget with python time limit

Tags: python, wget

I have a large text file of URLs which I have to download via wget. I have written a small python script which basically loops through each domain name and download them using wget (os.system("wget "+URL)). But the problem is that wget just hangs on a connection if the remote server doesn't reply after connecting.
How do I set a time limit in such a case? I want to terminate wget after some time if the remote server is not replying after connection.

Regards,

Comment: Don't use `os.system()`. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: if all you are doing is downloading from a text file I would just use wget, no need for python in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be less a question about python, and more a question about how to use wget.
in gnu wget, which you are likely using, the default number of retries is 20. you can set trieds using -t, perhaps wget -t0 would quickly skip it if the file fails to download. alternatively, you could use the -S flag to get sever response, and have python react appropriately. But, the most helpful options to you would be -T or timeout, set that to -T10 to have it timeout after ten seconds and move on.

#### edit:

If all you are doing is iterating through a list and downloading a list of URLs I would just use wget, no need  for python here. In fact, you can do it in one line

```
awk '{print "wget -t2 -T5 --append-output=wget.log \"" $0 "\""}' listOfUrls | bash
```

what this is doing is running through a list of urls, and calling wget, where wget tries to download the file twice, and waits 5 seconds before terminating the connection, it also appends the response to wget.log, which you can `grep` at the end looking for a 404 error.

Comment: This will fail horribly if the file `listOfURLS` contains any URLs that are not already percent encoded, containing spaces for example.

Comment: Good catch, but the question was not about the input. Preprocessing is best done ahead of time. I maintain that the wording of his original question negates the need for using python with this task.

Comment: Percent-encoding URLs is not preprocessing, it's part of the problem. URLs containing spaces are perfectly valid URLs, and your script can't handle them. (`wget` could, if quoted correctly, but your shell oneliner can't).

Comment: It certainly is preprocessing, but lets ignore this red hearing. I edited my one liner. This quotes it properly and should work, assuming bash shell.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--timeout seconds` argument to limit the time for a request. You can be more specific and use `--connect-timeout seconds` if needed. See the [wget Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use external tools such as `wget`. Use built-in `urllib2` to download files.
The documentation is available [here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is a cleaner library. For this question they have a timeout `request.get("http://www.to_url", timeout=0.1)`.

Comment: **It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks.** Strange statement they have on the main page. I used `urllib2` for a similar task (iterate over urls and download them), and the code was pretty small.

Comment: Well, have you used `urllib2` for example with a proxy **and** authentication? Have fun.

Comment: Nope, but I believe topicstarter does not need this either, so I suggested this package, as it is built-in and you don't need to install anything extra

Comment: I agree with this, but the real question is python the right tool for the job here? why not just use wget?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling the `wget` binary to do a task like this from Python. Use one of the available **HTTP libraries** for Python instead, you'll get much better error handling and control.

There's `urllib2` ([official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), [Missing Manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)) which is part of the standard library.

However, I'd strongly recommend to use the excellent [**`requests`** module](http://docs.python-requests.org) instead. It has a very clean API, makes simple tasks simple, as they should be, but still offers a ton of flexibility and fine grained control.

Using the `requests` module, you can [specify the timeout](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts) (in seconds) by using the `timeout` keyword argument like so:

```
response = requests.get(url, timeout=0.02)
```

If the timeout is exceeded, a `Timeout` exception will be raised, which you'll need catch and handle it any way you like.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ConnectionError

TIMEOUT = 0.02

urls = ['http://www.stackoverflow.com',
        'http://www.google.com']

for url in urls:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=TIMEOUT)
        print "Got response %s" % response.status_code
        response_body = response.content
    except (ConnectionError, Timeout), e:
        print "Request for %s failed: %s" % (url, e)
        # Handle however you need to ...
```

Sample output:

```
Request for http://www.stackoverflow.com failed: Request timed out.
Request for http://www.google.com failed: Request timed out.
```